# Firefox - log ionmonkey compilation and bailouts

Tags: javascript, firefox, compiler-construction, ionmonkey

I can start Google Chrome with `--js-flags="--trace-opt --trace-deopt"` to get a log of what the `V8` optimizer is compiling and what is falling out of the optimized execution, but is there anything comparable for Firefox IonMonkey?

Comment: Apparently there are flags to make IonMonkey [produce more logs](https://wiki.mozilla.org/IonMonkey#Debugging) that only work in debug builds. There's a ticket to [enable them in optimized builds](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1094150). Still not sure how you would set these from Firefox though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpiderMonkey has `IONFLAGS` environment variable (but not in the regular build, you have to build with `ac_add_options --enable-jitspew` to enable it, then run with `IONFLAGS=help` to see the available flags). It will probably take some time to learn how to use it though, since there is not much documentation.

For web developers work is underway on [JIT support in the Performance tool](https://wiki.mozilla.org/DevTools/Performance/JIT), dubbed "JIT Coach", and I could only find

- [the JIT opimizations panel](https://bug1143933.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=8583528) (switch to Performance tab of the DevTools, enable "Show JIT Optimizations" in the cog-menu, switch to the Call Stack view, and find a frame with JIT info denoted with an (i) icon)
- and an accompanying document: [JIT Optimization Strategies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JIT_Optimization_Strategies).

You can follow the dependencies of [bug 1143804](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1143804) to see the progress.